# Postgres pgcli: How to review transaction queries before commit?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using pgcli to execute a transaction on a postgresql database. I've come to the point where I'm almost ready to commit, I now want to review the queries I've ran. Is there a way to do this, either with pgcli or psql? I've looked at the [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-transactions.html) docs and [pgcli](https://www.pgcli.com/docs) docs but haven't found anything.

I've seen dbeaver records queries made during a transaction, but I'd like to see if it's possible using commandline tools.

The best solution I have so far is to hit the up arrow and page through recent commands until I see my last `BEGIN` query. After, I would page back down until I reach the most recent query.

Comment: Must of have been a short search: [History](https://www.pgcli.com/history)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've used that, but I don't think it fits my use case. It's a fuzzy search that returns a single result, a recently typed sql query that could be from days ago.

Comment: From the link ' ... Up/Down arrow can be used to navigate the history.  ...'.

Comment: Should have added that in `psql` you can do `\s` to get the history.